# jest test : Cannot read property 'status' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, jestjs, axis

I am trying to test a function with Axios get request. when I get a response I'm calling another function to filter the JSON document.

```
// sample.js

import axios from "axios";

public async getFruitData{
  const response = await axios.get("https://api.url.com/search/fruit", {
    params: {
      client_id: process.env.REACT_APP_UNSPLASH_TOKEN,
      query: term
    }
  });

return this.filtersResponse(response.data.results); //<---throwing error
};

filterResponse(detailsResponse) {
  const excludeFruit = ['apple'];
  return detailsResponse.filter(record => !excludeFruit.includes(record.fruit_type));
}
```

here my jest test

```
import axios from 'axios';
import Fruit from '../app/fruit';

jest.mock('axios');

test('it filter jsont fruit  ', async () => {
  mockedAxios.get.mockImplementationOnce(() => Promise.resolve({ data: 'test' }));
  const result = await getFruitData();
  expect(result).toBe({"data": "test"});
  expect(filterResponse(record)).toBeDefined()
});
```

when I run the test it gave me the following error -->     `TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined`

How can I test this scenario

Comment: I don't see any reference to `status` in your code, are you sure your mock is working correctly? You can place some `console.logs` in `getFruitData` to see how it's executing. Also, what is the variable `mockedAxios`?

Comment: `getFruitData` is a method of a Class? But you use it as a standalone function.